# Am I able to transfer my old sony vaio laptop's ram to my new ASUS GL552VW laptop?

Tags: laptop, memory, sony-vaio, transfer

I'm not that familiar with computer and specs and all that. I just know the basics like ram is good, get a good processor. Get a good graphics card, that's it basically.

My old laptop is a Sony Vaio Model: SVF152A29L and I am wondering if I can use it's ram (has 8 gb) and put it into my ASUS ROG GL552VW Laptop? 
Also, I don't have any big USBs or External Harddrives, is there an easy way for me to transfer some files over?

Comment: Typically, we expect people to ask a single question at a time. As for file transfer, you could just transfer them over the network with windows file sharing or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably can't. The [Asus is a newer system using DDR4](https://www.asus.com/sg/Notebooks/ROG-GL552VW/specifications/).

Sony's webpage is terrible, but since we're just making the switchover from DDR3 to 4 in the last 2 or so generations, chances are it runs low voltage DDR3.

Its totally incompatible.